# pivot view with dynamic data

Tags: c#, wcf, service, windows-phone-8

i'm working on a windows phone application using pivot view to preview data for the user, the data comes from a web service, then i put it in List then i add the item to the pivot view
but when i call the web service the view doesn't wait till i get the data from the server to add to the view and the view adds nothing , here is my code

```
   public class downloads : List<Downloaded>
{
    List<string> downoladedList = new List<string>();
    public downloads()
    {
        BuildCollection();
    }

    //private const string IMG_PATH = "../Images/";

    public ObservableCollection<Downloaded> DataCollection { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Downloaded> BuildCollection()
    {
        // int  x=0;
        Downloaded downObject = new Downloaded();
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client service = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        service.GetDownloadsCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.GetDownloadsCompletedEventArgs>(GetDownLoads);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000);
        service.GetDownloadsAsync(20019);



        DataCollection = new ObservableCollection<Downloaded>();
        foreach (var elem in downoladedList)
        {
            string[] elemProp = new string[8];
            elemProp = elem.Split('=');
            if (elemProp[3] == "1")
                elemProp[3] = "downloaded";
            else
                elemProp[3] = "in progress";

            DataCollection.Add(new Downloaded(elemProp[1], elemProp[3], "test.png"));
        }



        return DataCollection;
    }

    public void GetDownLoads(object sender, ServiceReference1.GetDownloadsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            downoladedList = e.Result.ToList<string>();


        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call `thread.sleep`. This will block entire UI thread.
Declare DataCollection = new ObservableCollection();
outside scope.
You should put all your code on completed like this :

```
 public void GetDownLoads(object sender, ServiceReference1.GetDownloadsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        downoladedList = e.Result.ToList<string>();

        foreach (var elem in downoladedList)
        {
        string[] elemProp = new string[8];
        elemProp = elem.Split('=');
        if (elemProp[3] == "1")
            elemProp[3] = "downloaded";
        else
            elemProp[3] = "in progress";

        DataCollection.Add(new Downloaded(elemProp[1], elemProp[3], "test.png"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {

    }
}
```